# test string using regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have an array of strings and would like to test it:

**Examples:**

```
$strings = array(
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/categories/view.html.php', // Match
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/index.html',  // Match
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/default.php',  // Match
    'install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/configuration.php', // Not match
    'configuration.php',  // Match
    'logs/error.php',  // Match
    'logs/index.html',  // Match
    'logs/joomla_update.php',  // Match
    'folder/logs/log.php',  // Not Match
    'update.php'  // Not match
);
```

I would like to define array of skipped folders and files

```
$skip = array('configuration.php', 'logs', 'tmp');
```

- logs and tmp will be at the begin of string;

And remove mathched from array of strings;
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why the 4th item doesn't match since the file is `configuration.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal answer for this problem would be as follows

```
    $strings = array(
        'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/categories/view.html.php', // Match
        'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/index.html',  // Match
        'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/default.php',  // Match
        'install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/configuration.php', // Not match
        'configuration.php',  // Match
        'logs/error.php',  // Match
        'logs/index.html',  // Match
        'logs/joomla_update.php',  // Match
        'folder/logs/log.php',  // Not Match
        'update.php'  // Not match
    );
   $result = preg_grep("/^(logs|tmp|configuration.php)/", $strings, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Which results with

```
Array
(
    [8] => folder/logs/log.php
    [9] => update.php
)
```

But this leaves little room for expansion. If you wanted to go with your method, where files are applied to the end and folders are applied to the beginning of the filtering then try this.

```
$strings = array(
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/categories/view.html.php', // Match
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/index.html',  // Match
    'tmp/install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/default.php',  // Match
    'install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/configuration.php', // Not match
    'configuration.php',  // Match
    'logs/error.php',  // Match
    'logs/index.html',  // Match
    'logs/joomla_update.php',  // Match
    'folder/logs/log.php',  // Not Match
    'update.php'  // Not match
);


$result = array_filter($strings, function($input){
    $skip = array('configuration.php', 'logs', 'tmp');
    foreach($skip as $toSkip){
        if (strpos($input, $toSkip) !== false) {
            // Directory Skip - Starts with
            if(strrpos($input, $toSkip, -strlen($input)) !== FALSE){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: the answer is wrong - look at question `"instal..." - Not match`

Comment: @splash58 you are correct. I misunderstood. Updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you test only from beginning of the string, regex will be slow solution.

Compare two string to decide save or not. And use array_filter to make new array

```
$skip = array('configuration.php', 'logs/', 'tmp/');

function notSkip($str) {
  global $skip;
  foreach($skip as $s) 
    if($s == substr($str, 0, strlen($s))) return false;
  return true;
}

$new = array_filter($strings, 'notSkip');
var_dump($new);
```

result

```
array(
  "install_55984fc72cf6a/admin/views/coupons/tmpl/configuration.php"
  "folder/logs/log.php"
  "update.php"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_grep` with the option `PREG_GREP_INVERT`. However using a simple array as filter is a little naive since you have conditions for each items:

```
$pattern = '~^(?:logs|tmp)(?:/|$)|(?:^|/)configuration\.php$~S';
$result = preg_grep($pattern, $strings, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

pattern details:

```
~                # pattern delimiter
^                # anchor for the start of the string
(?:logs|tmp)     # non-capturing group: "logs" or "tmp"
(?:/|$)          # non-capturing group: a slash or the end of the string

|                # OR

(?:^|/)          # non-capturing group: the start of the string or a slash 
configuration\.php
$                # end of the string
~S               # pattern delimiter, options*
```

Option `S` try to optimize alternations with literal characters.

Comment: Something wrong with configuration.php . For example this will be passed: plugins/arkevents/configuration/configuration.php

Comment: @user889349: I asked the question since an hour about this point, and you didn't give an answer. That's why you obtain wrong answers and you have two peoples that vote to close your post as 'too broad'.